# 3 digit integer to printable 3 digit string in nasm?

Tags: linux, string, assembly, x86, nasm

my program is nearing completion and is due tommrow. However i have identified the source of an issue. i am cycling through a few functions which roll a dice 1-6 and add that result to a buffer to keep score.Then when i want to print, i am only able to print single digit integers and anything with two digits such as 10 or greater loops through my write_number function infinetly until a seg fault results. How can i alter this algorithm to accomodate for up to three digit integers as the score will need to progress to 100 before the progam ends? unless anyone has a better previously coded algorithm since my assignment was to use a working function found online. please, any insight is greatly appreciated!

```
section .bss

userScore: resd 4
pcScore: resb 4

number: resd 4
digit: resd 4
count:  resd 4  

. . . . . . . . . . .

    cmp edx, 6 ;dice roll result
    call write_number
    jmp printReadOption

write_number:

    add dword[userScore], edx
    mov edx, dword[userScore]
    mov dword[number], edx
        mov eax, dword[number]
        mov ecx, 0Ah ;hex for 10
        cdq
        div ecx ;eax=number/10,edx=number%10
        mov dword[number], eax ;number= number/10
        add edx, 30h ;add 48 (30h) to make a printable character
        push edx ;push edx in to the stack and
        inc dword[count] ;increment count of numbers in the stack
        cmp dword[number], 0 ;if number != 0, loop again
        jne write_number

loop2:

        pop dword[digit] ;pop the digit from the stack and
        call write_digit ;write it
        dec dword[count] ;decrement the count
        cmp dword[count], 0 ; if count != 0, loop again
        jne loop2
        ret

write_digit:    ;Print score

    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, userScoreIs
    mov edx, userScoreIsLen
    int 80h

    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, digit ;score to print
    mov edx, 4
    int 80h
    ret
```

Comment: You keep adding to the number you're diving at the beginning od each loop iteration (`add dword[userScore], edx`), so the quotient probably never reaches zero, which would eventually lead to you pushing too many digits onto the stack.

Comment: you are correct! thank you very much! how do i mark my question answered so that you  may receive points or stacks or whatever form of reward system stack overflow uses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You keep adding to the number you're diving at the beginning of each loop iteration
`(add dword[userScore], edx),` 
so the quotient probably never reaches zero, which would eventually lead to you pushing too many digits onto the stack. complements of Michael as listed in the comment below.